# Is there a good way to share ax7 projects to GitHub or other version control system? axpp...

Tags: github, axapta, dynamics-ax7

Let's suppose, I have created a new model (with educational and/or demonstation purposes) and want to share AOT-objects from the model to GitHub.

Is there a good way to share ax7 projects to GitHub or other version control system?

1. axpp-file is an inbox functional.
   but binary file is not convenient format for git, I think.
2. git repository inside C:\AOSService\PackagesLocalDirectory\ is not good idea. I think.
3. The CoreXT tool is not available for clients, as far as I know.

What can you recommend to share ax7-projects?

Comment: If you created a new model, or even a new package, you could make the git repository of that? `C:\AOSService\PackagesLocalDirectory\MyNewPackage`.

Comment: Repository is one folder tree. Isn't it?

Is it good idiea to store project files inside C:\AOSService\PackagesLocalDirectory\MyNewPackage? .git, .gitattribute, License, Lint resultts and other non-axapta files...

Answer (score 0):

Usually in TFS, Used to create a new folder (eg: Metadata) and mapped to "\AOSService\PackagesLocalDirectory\" folder of Ax7 and another folder (eg: Projects) is created and mapped to "C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects". Similarly it should be possible for other version control system too.

Comment: Mapped? Do you mean mapping for working folders with Team Foundation Version Control?

For example, see https://stoneridgesoftware.com/setting-up-version-control-in-dynamics-365-for-operations-with-visual-studio/

screenshot: https://stoneridgesoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/VersionControl_MarkNelson12.png

If you mean this mapping, It is tool for Team Foundation Version Control only. My question was about GIT and similar systems